# Detect if Pseudo elements are in use on client side

Tags: css, html-email, pseudo-element, email-client

I’m writing an email which contains :before and :after to make some fancier bullet lists, and in the places where psuedo works its looking great. But obviously there are email clients that don’t render psuedo.

Is there a simple Media call/if I can put in to detect if these elements are being used (so I can format correctly for these clients)? Or do I just need to get a list of all the clients that won’t render them and put in a separate If for each?

I’m relatively new to all of this so appreciate the help!!

Comment: better write an email without using them, it's the easiest solution. You can easily replace a pseudo element with a basic element (div, span, etc)

Comment: You can use two column tables for beautiful bullets or you can use lists. Lists are easier to maintain but tables give you more flexibility. Use `:before` and `:after` for extra styling. Example adding words to a link in mobile maybe.

Answer (score 1):

According to Can I email, support isn't great - https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%3Abefore

My suggestion would be to stick to the default list styles and add customisation from there. Litmus covered this in detail which was super helpful to break out from the boring old black bullets or even bullets that match the colour of your text - https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-bulleted-lists-in-html-email/#fromHistory

But, if you're set on doing this you could use the Can I email result as a reference and then use https://howtotarget.email/ to then find how to target specific clients that don't support pseudo selectors.
Both of these resources are managed by industry members and are the most trusted resources in the industry.